# How to override a phtml from extension?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, menu, megamenu

I am using Mega Menu free extension from Ibnab. I want to override menu file to add custom li.

```
app/code/Ibnab/MegaMenu/view/frontend/templates/html/top-mega.phtml
```

Is there any way to override this file in my **custom theme** ?

I added custom html in this file but nothing is showing on frontend.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this file in your theme at `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Ibnab_MegaMenu/templates/html/top-mega.phtml`

Copy content of `top-mega.phtml` file to your theme's `top-mega.phtml` file you have just created. Now you can make modification to this `top-mega.phtml` file and your changes should reflect.